Creating smooth interactive line connections between DIVs in react
I have a site where I build some different quizzes and I want user to be able to specify connections between Quiz A options with Quiz B. So it means that Quiz A contains options: Opt1, Opt2, Opt3 and I want to connect visually Opt2 with Quiz B. There are plenty of different libs that allow me to connect visually but already providing HTML Elements or IDs such as LeaderLine or XArrows and moreover I even have my own variant which is actually working:
'use client';

import React from 'react';
import s from './connection.module.scss';

export const Connection = ({ start, end }: TConnection) => {
   const dx = end.x - start.x;
   const dy = end.y - start.y;

   // Calculate the midpoint
   const midX = start.x + dx / 2;
   const midY = start.y + dy / 2;

   // Calculate the length of the line
   const length = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

   // Offset the control point perpendicularly to the line
   const offset = 0.2 * length; // Adjust this value to make the curve more or less pronounced
   const controlX = midX - offset * (dy / length);
   const controlY = midY + offset * (dx / length);

   const minX = Math.min(start.x, end.x, controlX);
   const minY = Math.min(start.y, end.y, controlY);
   const maxX = Math.max(start.x, end.x, controlX);
   const maxY = Math.max(start.y, end.y, controlY);

   return (
      <svg
         className={s.connection}
         style={{ left: minX, top: minY }}
         width={maxX - minX}
         height={maxY - minY}
         viewBox={`0 0 ${maxX - minX} ${maxY - minY}`}
      >
         <path
            d={`M ${start.x - minX} ${start.y - minY} Q ${controlX - minX} ${
               controlY - minY
            } ${end.x - minX} ${end.y - minY}`}
            stroke="black"
            fill="transparent"
         />
      </svg>
   );
};

But it all works only with already known pair of {x, y} of start and end elements.
I need lib or any other way to actually draw a line like in Figma prototyping to be able to connect option with quiz in a interactive way

I think you could leverage your library using a temporary "end of line" element, to be dragged around on mouse move. You could create the terminator when clicking on the start element, drag it around on mouse move, and destroy it, along with the temporary connector, when dropping on the end element.

@AlbertoChiesa in fact I also need to recalculate options and quizzes position every time something changes. I'm worried if my code won't affect site the way that it won't be usable because of all these recalculations as moving a mouse is a constant path recalc. too

This are optimization problems, but there is no way, AFAICT, that you can accomplish what you want to do without creating a temporary element and update the svg on elements move. The problem of making the interaction fluid is a matter of limiting the updates to only the needed events. There are no shortcuts around that, I think.

@AlbertoChiesa as a true JS developer I was looking for a lib but ending up that I'll be doing everything by myself eh. Thanks for the answer!

Well, there is no reason to not use one of the libraries you linked... The thing you need to handle yourself is the creation and destruction of the temporary end-of-connector element, and moving its position via drag. I suppose you could also use a drag and drop library to handle the corresponding events, if you would like to.
